# Is it possible to set slide numbers shape into a PowerPoint presentation using office-js?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I know that we can create a slide number shape in PowerPoint.
This is a shape with <#> content as I see that.
Is it possible to implement that behavior using office-js?
When I try to set content of the shape as <#> using office-js, it just doesn't recognize it as a slide number placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've consulted internally at Microsoft. I'm sorry to report that there is no way to insert the slide number using Office.js.